# Computing the series$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{3^{k-1}+(2i)^k}{5^k}} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Show convergence of

$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{3^{k-1}+(2i)^k}{5^k}} &= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{3^{k-1}}{5^k}}+ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(2i)^k}{5^k}} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{3} \cdot \left( \frac{3}{5} \right) ^k} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ \left( \frac{2i}{5} \right )^k} \\
&= \frac{1}{3} \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ \left( \frac{3}{5} \right) ^k} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ \left( \frac{2i}{5} \right )^k} \\
\end{align}$

The first part of the sum converges because it is the geometric series with $q= \frac{3}{5}, 1> \left| \frac{3}{5} \right|$.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{2i}{5} \right)^k}$$

**Question:** Why does that series diverge ([WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20((2i)%5Ek)%2F(5%5Ek),%20n%3D1%20to%20infinity))?
I mean, if $q=\frac{2i}{5}, |q|<1$ then it should be the geometric series and thus converge?

Comment: May I know what is $i?$

Comment: Aon that WolframAlpha link, you have the sum on $n$, not $k$.  So of course it diverges,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by geometrics sum wfor any complex such that:   $|z|<1$ we have

Therefore

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} z^k= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} z^k =\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{z(1-z^{n+1})}{1-z}  = \frac{z}{1-z}  $$

since $\lim_{n\to\infty} z^n =0 $ since $|z|<1$.

Hence
 \begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{3^{k-1}+(2i)^k}{5^k}} &= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{3^{k-1}}{5^k}}+ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(2i)^k}{5^k}} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{3} \cdot \left( \frac{3}{5} \right) ^k} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ \left( \frac{2i}{5} \right )^k} \\
&= \frac{1}{3} \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ \left( \frac{3}{5} \right) ^k} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ \left( \frac{2i}{5} \right )^k} \\&= \frac{1}{3}\frac{\frac{3}{5}}{1-\frac{3}{5}}+ \frac{\frac{2i}{5}}{1-\frac{2i}{5}}
\end{align}

Comment: Isn't the geometric series convergence definded as $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{q^k} = \frac{1}{1-q}$? How do you get to $\frac{1}{3}\frac{\frac{3}{5}}{1-\frac{3}{5}}+ \frac{\frac{2i}{5}}{1-\frac{2i}{5}}$ ?

Comment: @jublikon you are right but here the sum start at $k=1$ which not the case in your formulas

Answer (score 1):

If $i$ satisfies $i^2=-1$ then
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{2i}5\right)^k$$
converges in $\Bbb C$ to
$$\frac{2i/5}{1-2i/5}=\frac{2i}{5-2i}=\frac{-4+10i}{29}$$
(geometric series) as $|2i/5|<1$.

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram Alpha says it diverges because you typed in $n=1$ to infinity instead of $k=1$ to infinity.  Correct the typo and it works.